# decorate standard python module

Tags: python

I'd like to decorate every function in a module (curses in my case) with a logger, but haven't done something like this before. Can you tell me where to read some documentation.

I'd like something like:

```
import curses as mycurses
import curses_wrapper as curses
```

where curses_wrapper is my module, and should catch all calls to whatevermodulefunctions, log it, and call the "real" curses function afterwards.

For the curious: I am using PyCharm on windows, and would like to debug a curses program. Since PyCharm cannot provide me a terminal, I cannot really debug the program.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067262/automatically-decorating-every-instance-method-in-a-class

Seems you could follow a similar reflection-based approach.

Comment: Similar, but I'd do it for a module, not for a class

Comment: the only thing I can propose to use own function for import and modify module attributes during import

Answer (score 1):

You can [iterate over all of the functions in a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module), decorate them, then add the decorated version to your own namespace.  You can't iterate this process, since our basic `Namespace` object doesn't play all that well with `inspect`, but I'm sure this can be extended to support that thing if need be.

```
import inspect
import types

class Namespace(object):
    pass

def decorate_module(module, decorator):
    namespace = Namespace()
    for n,v in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
            v = decorator(v)
        setattr(namespace, n, v)
    return namespace

def foo_decorator(f):
    def foo_func(*args, **kwargs):
        print("foo!")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return foo_func

inspect = decorate_module(inspect, foo_decorator)

print(inspect.ismodule(inspect))
```

> foo!
>   False